# Angular2 highlight a number of words in html string with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

In my Angular2 component, I receive a string from the parent component, that contains some HTML and it is being injected into the view. This part works! I now want to highlight a number of first words in that html (note: that number changes every time, let's say 15 for now).

**Code:**

**1)** html string (**content**) contains somethink like this:

```
<p>Hello, this is a <span> smaple text</span></p>
<p>More things to say here...</p>
<p>Perhaps an image as well here, or a link: <a> This is a link here</a></p>
<p>This is very long, did you read this?</p>
```

**2)** In Angular2 this string is injected into the component:

```
   <div [innerHTML]="content"> </div>

   <button type="submit" (click)="toggle()" >Toggle Highlight</button>
```

**3)** When toggle btn is clicked: the plan is to count 15(or whats specified) words in the html string, and inject a span(with green background) from start to word #15..

Right now, I am currently trying to simply inject a span with a green background colour around the whole html, like this:

```
toggle() {
    this.content = "<span style=\"background-color: green;\">"+ this.content +"</span>";
  }
```

Even this is not working, I also tried with a class, but it's not being picked up.
And there is another problem with inserting a span into this html as word 15 may be in a different tag which will cause problems.

Any suggestion if there is another way to highlight a number of words in string of html?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the correct way of doing it is **not** using:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"> </div>
```

As **innerHTML** won't support any hardcoded styles in tags.

Instead in html use:

```
<div #dataContainer></div>
```

And then in Angular TS:

```
this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML =  `<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 210, 0, 0.45);">${this.content}</span>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for this would probably be a directive or a pipe. Basically add directive to the component, check the length and then add the class to the element ref.

something similar to this:

[Angular 2/4 : How to check length of input's value using directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346486/angular-2-4-how-to-check-length-of-inputs-value-using-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `span` use `div` to set highlighted background color as:

```
toggle() {
  this.content = `<div style="background-color: green;">${this.content}</span>`;
}
```

Also you can use back tick (`) to simplify the string expression.

Comment: I like the idea of simplifying string expression, but this still does not apply/update the view with new style. However, I now found the answer. Thanks